# Google maps API and Exception when running the app

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm developing an app the contain google maps so I followed the instructions in Google page https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start

When I sync the file everything works fine, but each time I try to run it I got an exception that said:

```
    Error:Execution failed for task 

':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: 
   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException:
   Process 'command 'C:\Program    Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin\java.exe''   
   finished with non-zero exit value 3
```

**This is my gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.tellme.mapwithmarker"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

until now there is nothing in the project expect the map fragment and the main java class.

I will appreciate any help for solving this error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using all play services in your project, use the required one.

Use 
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1’

instead of

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'

Reference Link :
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: Thank you so much, my problem solved when I use your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add this below buildTypes in gradle

```
dexOptions {
    // incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"

}
```

Comment: by using this it took time to compile and run the app

Comment: for the first time it will take

Answer (score 0):

**You need to change**

```
 `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'`
```

**to**

```
`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'`
```

**use Below Gradle file it will work fine i have checked at my side**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {

        applicationId "com.example.tellme.mapwithmarker"

        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
   // compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```